Error in dfidx function: Indices do not define unique observations in R for Mixed Multinomial Logit Model
I try to prepare dataframe for mixed multinomial logit model using mlogit package.
My data looks as follows:



PART_ID
Trial_no
Expected_Return
Risk
Curr_item_Price
Rating_distortion
Popularity_distortion
Choice
Option_ID




14203F28
11
4
4
1108
-0.9
-27
1
1


14203F28
11
2
6
936
1.4
8
0
2


14203F28
11
2
6
1094
1.4
8
0
3


14203F28
11
2
5
1150
-1.7
29
0
4


14203F28
12
8
2
879
2.3
18
0
1



Each participant (PART_ID) have a bunch of choice opportunities (Trial_no) in which they choose one (Choice) among possible options (Option_ID).
I try to reorganise data for mlogit function using dfidx, as in "nested example" from dfidx docs.
Even thought that I checked that there's only one unique observation for PART_ID, Trial_no, Option_ID my error message displays the opposite.
# load exemplary set
data("JapaneseFDI", package = "mlogit")
JapaneseFDI <- dplyr::select(JapaneseFDI, 1:8)

JapaneseFDI |>
  group_by(firm, country, region) |>
  summarise(count = n()) |>
  filter(count != 1)

# Output: 0 rows

res |>  
  group_by(PART_ID, Trial_no, Option_ID) |> 
  summarise(count = n()) |>
  filter(count != 1)

# Output: 0 rows


JP1b <- dfidx(JapaneseFDI, 
              idx = list("firm", c("region", "country")),
              choice = "choice")
# Works fine

mlogit_data <- dfidx(res, 
                     idx = list("PART_ID", c("Trial_no", "Option_ID")),
                     choice = "Choice")

#Error in dfidx(res, idx = list("PART_ID", c("Trial_no", "Option_ID")),  : 
#  the two indexes don't define unique observations

I see this and I'm aware, that dfidx function is build rather for two indexes, not three, but I think my problem is similarly to nested example from documentation.
Can someone please explain to me what I did wrong?
> sessionInfo()
R version 4.4.0 (2024-04-24)
Platform: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
Running under: Linux Mint 21.3

Matrix products: default
BLAS:   /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/openblas-pthread/libblas.so.3 
LAPACK: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/openblas-pthread/libopenblasp-r0.3.20.so;  LAPACK version 3.10.0


attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
 [1] lmtest_0.9-40   zoo_1.8-12      mlogit_1.1-1    dfidx_0.0-5     lubridate_1.9.3 forcats_1.0.0  
 [7] stringr_1.5.1   dplyr_1.1.4     purrr_1.0.2     readr_2.1.5     tidyr_1.3.1     tibble_3.2.1   
[13] ggplot2_3.5.1   tidyverse_2.0.0

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] utf8_1.2.4        generics_0.1.3    lattice_0.22-6    stringi_1.8.4     hms_1.1.3         magrittr_2.0.3   
 [7] grid_4.4.0        timechange_0.3.0  Formula_1.2-5     fansi_1.0.6       scales_1.3.0      Rdpack_2.6       
[13] cli_3.6.3         rlang_1.1.4       crayon_1.5.3      rbibutils_2.2.16  bit64_4.0.5       munsell_0.5.1    
[19] withr_3.0.0       tools_4.4.0       parallel_4.4.0    tzdb_0.4.0        colorspace_2.1-0  vctrs_0.6.5      
[25] R6_2.5.1          lifecycle_1.0.4   bit_4.0.5         vroom_1.6.5       MASS_7.3-61       pkgconfig_2.0.3  
[31] pillar_1.9.0      gtable_0.3.5      glue_1.7.0        statmod_1.5.0     xfun_0.45         tidyselect_1.2.1 
[37] rstudioapi_0.16.0 knitr_1.47        compiler_4.4.0   

